# Set Text Color to textColorPrimary in Android Studio programmatically?

Tags: java, android, textview, dynamic-programming

I'd like to change the text color of my dynamically generated TextView to android.R.attr.textColorPrimary. So if dark theme is deactivated it should be black, if activated it should be white. Like a hardcoded TextView.

I tried that:

```
//Get the primary text color of the theme
    TypedValue typedValue = new TypedValue();
    Resources.Theme theme = getApplication().getTheme();
    theme.resolveAttribute(android.R.attr.textColorPrimary,typedValue,false);
    TypedArray arr = getApplicationContext().obtainStyledAttributes(typedValue.data, new int[]{
            android.R.attr.textColorPrimary});
    int primaryColor = arr.getColor(0,-1);
    tV1.setTextColor(primaryColor);
```

The color changed to black, but it's always black and it won't change if I activate or deactivate dark theme on os.

Comment: `getApplication().getTheme()` - have you tried using activitys theme instead?

Comment: how could i call that?

Comment: Oh yes. I have to call it like this.getTheme() and this.obtainStyledAttributes. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I just had to change `getApplication(). to this.`

```
//Get the primary text color of the theme
TypedValue typedValue = new TypedValue();
Resources.Theme theme = this.getTheme();
theme.resolveAttribute(android.R.attr.textColorPrimary,typedValue,false);
TypedArray arr = this.obtainStyledAttributes(typedValue.data, new int[]{
        android.R.attr.textColorPrimary});
int primaryColor = arr.getColor(0,-1);
tV1.setTextColor(primaryColor);
```